# Fit data to exponential distribution and create generator function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

I have a set of arrival data over a short 24h period where the inter-arrival intervals seem to model an exponential distribution. My goal is to fit this to an exponential distribution so that I can use it as a generator to model arrivals for periods more than the initial 24h window.

```
Sample:
248.69
250.01
287.73
302.17
318.03
357.66
389.87
392.82
395.99
406.47
446.29
466.47
475.52
487.2
496.85
500.02
522.95
547.09
582.78
593.67
612.46
680.63
745.35
```

Which leads to

```
Difference:
1.32
37.72
14.44
15.86
39.63
32.21
2.95
3.17
10.48
39.82
20.18
9.05
11.68
9.65
3.17
22.93
24.14
35.69
10.89
18.79
68.17
64.72
```

Plotting the entire difference dataset on a histogram gives this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NTET.png

Ideally I'd be able to obtain some variables where I can plug it into a function like expovariate to model variables like so:

```
def arrivals(lambda):
    return random.expovariate(lambda)
```

I found a suggestion for the following function but I have no idea how to use the printed variables:

> 0.023493173851297056
>   [[65.70015487]]

```
from math import exp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

def model(x, p):
    return p*np.exp(-p*x)

def expfit(df):
    X = df.index.values.reshape(-1,1).flatten().tolist()
    Y = df.values.flatten().tolist()
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(model, X, Y)
    print (popt[0])
    print (pcov)

arrivals = pd.read_csv("arrivals.csv")
expfit(arrivals.dropna().diff().dropna().to_frame())
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: " I have no idea how to use..." is not a clear enough question. What is your exact problem? [ask]

Comment: @Julien From the curve_fit function above, I get the variables 0.023493173851297056 [[65.70015487]] which I have no idea how to turn into a function that generates intervals. I tried plugging it into random.expovariate(0.023493173851297056) but the distribution does not look like the original dataset

Comment: What have you used for `x` and `Y`? Can't help without a [mcve]...

Comment: @Julien I used the original dataset loaded into a pandas dataframe so the differences get indexed, then separated them into x and y with ```X = df.index.values.reshape(-1,1) Y = df.values```. I edited the original post for clarification